# In PHP, When using explode(); How do I deal with two delimiters in a row in the string?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

So; I'm exploding a card list string, the delimiter is " `;` ".

One string can, for example, be " `creature;;1;;;;;1;1;;;2` ".

This gives me an array with the length 5.

Another card is " `creature;;3;;4;;2;3;2;` "

I need arrays with the same length and the values at the same positions, so how do I achieve this?

Basically I want the explode to make an (empty) element in the array from "`;;`".

I hope you can understand my question, since it's not easy to explain!

Thanks for any help :)

patty

Comment: cant understand your requirement,

Comment: What else are you doing beside explode()? because explode() will create empty elements

Comment: Please [post real code](https://3v4l.org/ApcRO). Don't make us guess.

Comment: @PattyLi Look at my answer thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How is `explode` **NOT** working for you?

```
php > var_dump(explode(';', 'a;;b'));
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Note that the dumped array does have 3 elements, with the second one being empty, as expected.

Comment: This is weird... It does NOT show empty ones for me :c

Answer (score 0):

Its the normal behaviour of the explode function

```
<?php
$string = "creature;;1;;;;;1;1;;;2";
$splitted = explode(";", $string);

var_dump($splitted);

$string = "creature;;3;;4;;2;3;2;";
$splitted = explode(";", $string);

var_dump($splitted);
```

Output is

```
 array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "creature"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(0) ""
  [11]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "creature"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the empty array elements

Comment: I think he wants the exact opposite (which is the default behaviour anyway).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are just right. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### `explode` in PHP:

`explode` splits a string into an array by a text delimiter. This is done by taking the area of the string between two characters matching the delimiter and pushing it to an array. Thus, if there are 2 delimiters right after each other, then an empty array entry is added (as other answers have stated). **This is default, expected behavour of `explode`**.

### Array Processing:

If you want to get rid of all empty entries, you could do something like this:

```
$split = explode(";","creature;;1;;;;;1;1;;;2");
$final  = Array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($split);$i++) {
    if ($split[$i]!="") {
        array_push($final,$split[$i]);
    }
}
```

This is a basic example of array processing, and it works like so:

- First, we `explode` the string by the requested delimiter. We call the result `$split`.
- Next, we create a new array, which is empty. This is called `$final`.
- We then create a `for` loop, which iterates through every item in the array `$split`.
- The `if` statement checks if the entry is blank, if it **isn't**, then we push the item to the array `$final`.
- At the end of this, `$final` only contains the elements we want.